# Rails: Creating/updating has_many relationships for existing has_many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

Given:

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customers, inverse_of: :group
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers, allow_destroy: true
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group, inverse_of: :customers
end
```

I want to create/update a group and assign existing customers to the group e.g.:

```rb
Group.new(customers_attributes: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }])
```

This does not work though because Rails will just throw `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Customer with ID=1 for Group with ID=` (or `ID=the_group_id` if I'm updating a `Group`). Only way I've found to fix it is just extract `customers_attributes` and then do a separate `Customer.where(id: [1,2]).update_all(group_id: 'groups_id')` after the `Group` `save!` call.

Anyone else come across this? I feel like a way to fix it would be to have a key like `_existing: true` inside `customers_attributes` (much like `_destroy: true` is used to nullify the foreign key) could work. Or does something like this violate a Rails principle that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to use nested attributes for this, you can instead set the association_ids attribute directly:

```rb
Group.new(customer_ids: [1, 2])
```

This will automatically update the group_id on each referenced Customer when the record is saved.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that. So while that's fine for creating a new group, if you do that when updating a group, it erases any previous customers that may have been attached to that `Group`. I'm kind of looking for an all-in-one solution.